# matrix[matrix]: what does it mean?

Tags: r

I have a matrix storing some indices and an other on with given values. I wanted to access these values by taping matrix[matrix] but I can't figure out what is produced.

A quick example :

```
indices = matrix(c(1,1,3,2,3,2), 3, 2)
data = matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
data[indices]
 [1] 4 7 6
```

while I was expecting:

```
> rbind(data[1,indices[1,]], data[2, indices[2,]], data[3, indices[3,]])
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    8
[3,]    9    6
```

I have no idea what R is doing.

Thanks !

Comment: Try `data[cbind(rep(1:3,each=2),c(t(indices)))]` to extract the elements

Comment: Re your question, R is indexing by row/col combination that you've inserted into `data` via `indices`, i.e., *"select first row and second column from `data`"* which is `4`. Then *"select first row again and third column"* which is `7`, etc.

Comment: Ok I got your point, the first column of indices is interpreted as a row index and the second as the column index, thanks

Comment: but there is still something wired to me with this notation as with `indices` matrix 3x3 (or with more columns) then `data[indices]` gives `c(indices)`

Comment: Don't know what you mean by that

Comment: try `data[cbind(indices, indices)]` you'll get `c(cbind(indices, indices))`

Comment: @clemlaflemme : You don't get `c(cbind(indices, indices))`; it just happens here because of the values in `data`. See: `data[] = sample(data); data[cbind(indices, indices)]`. When, in matrix subsetting `x[matrix_subset]`, holds `ncol(matrix_subset) != length(dim(x))` then "matrix_subset" loses its "dim" attribute and you get `x[c(matrix_subset)]`.

Comment: thanks @alexis_laz it makes all clear now

Comment: If it is an answer @alexis_laz write it as an answer :D. I would suggest you to visualize how indices are  and how matrix is... (I can't at the moment)